# Почему выдает ошибку в валидности и как её исправить?

Tags: xml, xhtml

> Line 25, Column 28: element "center" undefined

```
<div class='post_ 1'><center><img src='/sys/ images/icons/ stars/2.png' /> <img sr…
```

Comment: Из вашего вопроса ничего не понятно, приведите пожалуйста достойный пример.

Answer (score 2):

А вы валидируете под каким доктайпом? Просто в XHTML тэг center считается устаревшим и соответственно на него ругается валидатор. По теории он еще должен ругнутся на одинарные кавычки =).

Используйте вместо тега стиль:

```
<div class='post_ 1' style="text-align:center;">
```

Comment: Нельзя использовать style, лучше в цсс прописать div.post_1{text-align:center;}

Comment: Нельзя и лучше - разные вещи ;)

Answer (score 0):

text-align: center тоже не совсем правильное решение для центрирования.
Правильнее будет центрировать изображение с помощью установки левого и правого полей в значение auto. (например, margin: 0 auto;).

А в остальном надо понимать, в каком режиме работает браузер и какой синтаксис допускается в этом режиме. Как известно, их 3: стандартный, почти стандартный и режим совместимости... Ну, я думаю, достаточно источников существует по данной теме.